# flutter bottomsheet with overlay button on top

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Can someone give guidance on how to create a bottomsheet with a button on top like below?

I think typically we should be able to achieve it using a stack widget. But not sure how to do this with a bottomsheet. Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Stack takes the full space available from the parent. Use positionned Widget with a négative value can easily make it. But your button won't be clickable. Use Overlay or make the parent widget bigger than the smallest widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test Bottom Sheet app',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo '),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text("Body"),),
      bottomSheet:getBottomSheet() , //Main Center
    ); //Scaffold
  }
  Widget getBottomSheet(){
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
          Stack(
            children: [


            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
              child: Card(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ListView(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0),
                      child: SizedBox(height: 50, child: Text("Postpone Start")),
                    ),
                      SizedBox(height: 50, child: Text("Postpone Start")),
                      SizedBox(height: 50, child: Text("Postpone Start")),
                  ],),
                ),
              ),
            ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Card(
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      child: FlatButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text("Header"))),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I need to show that UI by calling, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html, I hope the above sample works for it.

Comment: Thank you, it worked by adding  Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none, and adding the Row widget in a positioned widget,  Positioned(
              top: -30,
              left: 10,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Card(
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      child:
                          FlatButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Header"))),
                ],
              ),
            ),

Comment: Feels good that it worked for you @SowmyanSoman